# 4D SSL Client Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, 4d-database

I'm trying to find a way to integrate a client-side ssl certificate to a 4d server, in order to send SOAP calls to a Web service. So far I have only encountered tutorials on server-side ssl certificate tutorial. 4D server version is 16.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the commands as **HTTP Request**, if the server asks for a Client certificate, 4D will use the certificates saved in "ClientCertificatesFolder" near the structure file.

You have to create it or you can set a custom folder using the command

```
HTTP SET CERTIFICATES FOLDER (folder path)
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work just fine. Before your comment, I have planned to resort to using python as an external process, since I'm using a python script to sign the xml record anyway, so might as well use the requests library.